# Ionic2 client + Meteor server, which approach is better?

Tags: authentication, meteor, ionic2, meteor-accounts

I want to have Meteor as a server and Ionic2 as a client. I currently have a headache with authentifiacation. It seems that there are two different approaches:

1. First is use of Meteor server and Meteor client with `ionic-angular` library. This approach described here

https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/ionic2

I guess the advantage of this method is use of Meteor native architecture, on the other hand I guess we're using Ionic2 just like a subframework and maybe loosing some stuff from native Ionic2.

2. The second is using separate Meteor server ('client' folder deleted completely) and native Ionic2. This approach described here

https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/authentication

This option is vice versa: use of native Ionic2, but it has to use libraries like `meteor-client-side`, `accounts-base-client-side`, `accounts-password-client-side` etc, which I'm not sure are native for Meteor.

The first approach looks better, because there is a ready-to-use UI component for authentification. But I wonder what issues I would have, when I come to the step of completing my applications for different types of devices.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These approaches are essentially the same for the authentication itself.
What you are pointing out is more about what mobile platform to choose to develop and run mobile projects.

In the first case, you use Meteor's built-in Cordova platform to run the app and Meteor's compiler and bundler plugins (like TypeScript package or Meteor core packages for Babel and UglifyJS etc) to develop the app. In the second case, you develop and run the app solely on Ionic 2 CLI.

But from the app logic point of view these approaches are absolutely same: you import the same Ionic 2 components and use the same Meteor packages with the only difference in the second case is that these packages are now NPMs not Atmosphere ones (essentially though they contain the same scripts since these NPMs are built from Atmosphere packages).

The reason why What’sApp clone is built in that way that differs from the Socially’s one is simply described in the README of 
the What’sApp repo (see https://github.com/Urigo/Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp). If to repeat: since Ionic is a one of the best Web frameworks that specializes solely in building mobile apps, it’s reasonable to guess that it’ll be (and likely it is) much more powerful in building them than Meteor itself. From that point of view the second approach seems more future-proof, I would say. You could think even of building your project in some way that will allow you to substitute Meteor easily with some another framework if you decide to use it at some point in the future.

If you are though concerned about using those NPMs mentioned in the second case (e.g., if the process of building them doesn’t look transparent to you), you could try this project https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-client-bundler to bundle Atmosphere packages you need into separate scripts and use them after.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's very helpful! I will give a try for both methods. I think the second way is much more common if I would start using Apollo, besause server-client relations this case get weeker. And thank you for the link bundler, I wouldn't find it myself.